# No results for a specific user in Twitter search API

Tags: api, search, twitter, atom-feed

For some reason, when searching on one specific Twitter user, the search API return nothing. (ie http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=+from%3ATWITTERHANDLE_A) TWITTERHANDLE_A here is the Twitter account name. This user has been active for over a month, has had many RTs, @s and has sent such tweets out as well.

Meanwhile, I created a new Twitter account - we will call it TWITTERHANDLE_B. Immediately after I created the account, I sent 1 tweet and performed the same search as above (http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=+from%3ATWITTERHANDLE_B)
The tweet was returned.

Is there ANYWAY to find out if and/or why a particular user would be blocked from search results? Thanks so much for any help... I'm going crazy here. Twitter's documentation just says sometimes a user's tweets won't be searched!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you refer to has a link to this page:
http://support.twitter.com/forums/10713/entries/42646

The bottom entry addresses your issue, hopefully you can fix it that way.

Bear in mind the search API only grabs results from the last couple of weeks, so if the user hasn't tweeted in a while then there won't be any results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I came across this a few days ago. Unfortunately, it doesn't offer any remedy. Just "your account should eventually show in search." Very scientific :)

Comment: You could try emailing support@twitter.com. They might be able tell you why your account was flagged not to be in search.

Comment: In my test of the search API I made a simple mistake, and this may be relevant to your situation. I hadn't tweeted anything in a couple weeks and the search API only gets results from within the last couple weeks. After I made a new tweet that was returned.

Comment: Yep, for the last few weeks, I've seen only my last four days of tweets, so it could be as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try not using the Search API and grab the results directly:

http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/-username-.json

Works fine for http requests at least... >_<

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am actually sending search parameters.